# Codename One - Can`t make simple build

Tags: java, java-8, codenameone

I`ve try to send basic Android Build as tutorial says but I`m getting this error. PS: I never would made any build before, and every day this message persists. (I`m using the Free account).

build-for-android-device:
[codeNameOne] You have a build in progress within the queue. Only one build may be active at a time

Someone may help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at our support logs I think this was an issue that was resolved by a support engineer. The issue was related to an email account containing a `+` sign in the address specifically `name+name@domain.com`

Since our system uses emails to identify users this caused some issues and failed to show builds that went thru. So there was a build stuck in queue that never got built...

Comment: Understood. But this isn't a issue to solve? (since a lot of email providers like "Gmail" allow uses of "alias" like that? (my scenario for example)

Comment: I'm not sure if it still exists. We rewrote the entire process so it's possible it works fine now. Since we migrated to an SSO solution our dependency on email addresses is significantly reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your IDE, operation system.

You have queue of build right now.